# Visualforce: Unknown Inner class property

Tags: apex, visualforce

I havee this variable in my controller

```
public Categoria cat {Get;Set;}
```

If I print this one `{!cat}` in my visualforce the result is:

```
Categoria:[isSelect=true, nombre=asdasdad]
```

The problem is when I try to access to the element *isSelect*

if i use `{!Cat.isSelect}` I get an error **(Unknown Property)**

what is the problem?

Comment: @lopex Is `Categoria ` a class name?

Comment: yes, is a inner class inside the extension controller `public class Categoria{
  Boolean isSelect {get;set;}
  String  nombre {get;set;}
  public Categoria(){}
 }`

Comment: As you said that it is an inner class, I believe you the inner class isSelect should be public and also it should have {get;set;} i.e. it should be defined as `public class Categoria { public String isSelect {get;set;} public  String nombre{get;set;} } `Please add public access modifier

Comment: Writing an answer so that anyone else with same issue  can can find it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.I forgot the access modifier 'public' in the inner class.

Answer (score 4):

As you said that it is an inner class, I believe you the inner class variable  isSelect should be public and also it should have getter setter.

It should be defined as

```
public class Categoria 
{ 
     public String isSelect {get;set;} 
     public String nombre{get;set;} 
}
```

Please add public access modifier